# What are the ways to use RxPHP in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to use Rxphp in laravel, i have done many searches but not find any way to use it. There is lot of things about Rxjava in android or Rxjs but not for laravel.

Comment: Could you tell us more about what you want to achieve? Laravel already has events/observers built in, maybe it is not necessary to combine the 2?

Comment: Use for better performance of my website, Because Rxphp provides Api's to achieve multi-threading. That's why i want to use it. I don't no about laravel Observers. Is it provide the same thing that Rxphp provide?